# How to iterate over text file having multiple-words-per-line using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sh

I know how to iterate over lines of text when the text file has contents as below:

```
abc  
pqr  
xyz
```

However, what if the contents of my text file are as below,

```
abc xyz  
cdf pqr  
lmn rst
```

and I need to get values "abc" stored to one variable and"xyz" stored to another variable. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the delimiter is a space then you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

ALLVALUES=()
while read line
do
    ALLVALUES+=( $line )
done < "/path/to/your/file"
```

So after, you can just reference an element by `${ALLVALUES[0]}` or `${ALLVALUES[1]}` etc

Comment: This also exposes the words to globbing, etc. and may not be appropriate.

Comment: @123 `read -a` instead of what?  I edited my answer a few seconds ago btw, perhaps you were talking about my previous post.

Comment: Instead of reading the line then making an array from it... Your new answer makes no sense, why do you create the vars array only to access all the members and put them in another?

Comment: @EtanReisner can you elaborate on globbing, perhaps by giving an example?  Sometimes I answer SO questions to learn as well :)

Comment: @123 ah you're right, just keep as one array and append.  Edited, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Try this with a file that contains `foo * bar` and see what your `ALLVALUES` array contains as entries. And the `read -a` comment is that `read` can already populate an array with the words of the line directly. So `while read -r -a _a; do allvalues+=("${a[@]}"); done` would be safer.

Answer (score 3):

`read` splits the line by `$IFS` as many times as you pass variables to it:

```
while read var1 var2 ; do
    echo "var1: ${var1} var2: ${var2}"
done
```

You see, if you pass var1 and var2 both columns go to separate variables. But note that if the line would contain more columns var2 would contain the whole remaining line, not just column2.

Type `help read` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read every word in a file into a single array you can do it like this:

```
arr=()
while read -r -a _a; do
   arr+=("${a[@]}")
done < infile
```

Which uses `-r` to avoid `read` from interpreting backslashes in the input and `-a` to have it split the words (splitting on `$IFS`) into an array. It then appends all the elements of that array to the accumulating array while being safe for globbing and other metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

This awk command reads the input word by word:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '1' file

abc
xyz
cdf
pqr
lmn
rst
```

To populate a shell array use awk command in *process substitution*:

```
arr=()
while read -r w; do
   arr+=("$w")
done < <(awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '1' file)
```

And print the array content:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="abc" [1]="xyz" [2]="cdf" [3]="pqr" [4]="lmn" [5]="rst")'
```